# Can't Login to Wordpress, No Data Received Error

Tags: login, errors, dashboard, server

I can't login to my Wordpress dashboard. When I go to example.com/wp-admin and enter my info, it returns a page that says "No Data Received: Unable to load this page because the server sent no data." I've looked on the Wordpress forums and Google and here, but I haven't found any answers as to why this is happening. Some things I read suggested that it might be an issue with my host, so I contacted GoDaddy, but they are insisting it is a Wordpress issue. Does anyone know how I can fix this? I'm at a loss.

Comment: Are you using any sort of "theme my login" type plugin? Perhaps try backing up your plugin folder (simply rename it), then try to login.

Comment: No, it's just the standard WP login...

Comment: I've been reading a lot about this, and I know this doesn't really help, but this is most likely a server issue. Most of the reports I've seen are folks hosting with GoDaddy. 

I know their support are insisting it's a WP issue, but this probably isn't the truly the case. That's not a WP error. It's a browser error when you can't communicate with the server.

I'd probably "insist" back that they look into the problem. As they say, the squeaky wheel gets the grease. If it's not a GoDaddy issue, I suppose it could be an ISP issue.

Comment: I'll try to get on them about it. In the meantime, if anyone has any suggestions, I welcome them.

Answer (score 3):

Look at your `.htaccess` file in your `public_html` folder for your WordPress installation.

It seems that when with GoDaddy hosted on the windows package, you need the following inheritance set for rewrite in your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteOptions inherit
RewriteEngine on
```

That solved my problem on `index.php`.